# How do I access the contents of the clipboard from within a headless puppeteer test?

Tags: clipboard, puppeteer

I'm writing a test that uses puppeteer to test a component that copies something to the clipboard when it is interacted with. I want to test that the contents of the clipboard are correct after interacting. Other resources like [this github issue](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/2147) mention using a tool like [clipboardy](https://github.com/sindresorhus/clipboardy) to accomplish this. I tried using that and it works locally, but when run in my headless CI server, it complains about not having access to the X environment. Is there a way to access the clipboard without starting an X server?

I'm writing a test like this:

```
const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
const page = await browser.newPage();
await page.goto('https://mypage.com');

await page.click('#my-component');

// This fails in a headless environment
expect(clipboardy.readSync()).toEqual("Some text");
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

By adding the `'clipboard-read'` permission to puppeteer and using the
Clipboard API, you can run `navigator.clipboard.readText()` to read from the
clipboard in a test. This will work even in a headless environment:

```js
const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
const context = browser.defaultBrowserContext();
await context.overridePermissions(/* browser origin */, ['clipboard-read']);
const page = await browser.newPage();
await page.goto('https://mypage.com');

await page.click('#my-component');

expect(await page.evaluate(() => navigator.clipboard.readText()))
  .toEqual("Some text");
```

[Documentation](https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v5.2.1&show=api-browsercontextoverridepermissionsorigin-permissions) of context.overridePermissions()

Comment: What is "config.APPLICATION_URL"?

Comment: Thanks for self-answering, by the way, super useful :)

Comment: @Eduard You're welcome! Thanks for improving my answer.

Comment: @EmilyEisenberg I have a button when clicked a URL link is getting copied to the clipboard, and I need to past that in a new tab, in that case, how am I supposed to add the origin?

Comment: Where do I get the browser origin from?

Answer (score 2):

In my case I couldn't override permissions, as Eduard suggested, because it requires to give origin as a parm. I'm injecting html content in my test to the page via setContent so the page address is `about:blank`. Setting origin to `"*"` doesn't work either, nor `undefined`.

I have ended up mocking the clipboard api:

```js
await page.evaluate((dataInternal) => {
    // mock clipboard
    let clipboardText = null;
    window["navigator"]["clipboard"] = {
        writeText: text => new Promise(resolve => clipboardText = text),
        readText: () => new Promise(resolve => resolve(clipboardText)),
    }
}
```

then you can just do the following assert:

```js
expect(await page.evaluate(() => navigator.clipboard.readText())).toBe("your text in clipboard");
```

Comment: Does this still work? I'm getting "DOMException: No valid data on clipboard."

Answer (score 1):

In my chrome, `navigator.clipboard = ...` did not work, because `navigator` had getter and setter for `clipboard`.

Mocking clipboard:

```
await page.evaluate(() => {
    const clipboard = {
        async writeText(text: string) {
            this.text = text;
        },
    };
    Object.defineProperty(navigator, 'clipboard', { value: clipboard });
});
```

Reading clipboard content:

```
page.evaluate(() => navigator.clipboard.text);
```