# Bypass Document Focus requirement in Chrome / Puppeteer

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium, google-chrome, puppeteer

When querying `navigator.clipboard` from puppeteer, I run into the following error:

```
DOMException: Document is not focused.
```

Example code (You can run it in Chrome to reproduce):

```
navigator.clipboard
            .read()
            .then(async (clipboards) => { })
```

Is it possible to disable the document focus check somehow? i.e. using chromeflags.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there any way in JavaScript to focus the document (content area)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6976486/is-there-any-way-in-javascript-to-focus-the-document-content-area)

Comment: @code nope, this only works if the window is already focused.

Comment: Hmm, will this post help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60158746/how-do-i-access-the-contents-of-the-clipboard-from-within-a-headless-puppeteer-t

Comment: @code The answer there returns me an empty string. Might be a regression. `page.click` does help with running it headfully(?) but headless hangs.

Comment: Don't think so but this is a list of chromium flags: https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/

Comment: @SlavaKnyazev have you found a way? I am looking for that too (in Chrome) to paste content into a page that has no focus...

Comment: @vdegenne If you run it headfully, you can send a ctrl+c keystroke to it which will do a paste from the clipboard. That’s how I did it for myself.