# How to copy an image to clipboard in pupeteer

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have an API that converts FEN (Forsyth-Edwards Notation) to image. However, the issue lies in the download and upload process, which is considerably slower compared to the copy-and-paste method. Thus, I aim to utilize Puppeteer to swiftly copy an image from a URL to the clipboard, facilitating its seamless insertion into an input field.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I access the contents of the clipboard from within a headless puppeteer test?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60158746/how-do-i-access-the-contents-of-the-clipboard-from-within-a-headless-puppeteer-t)